# No sound in Windows while inside a Minecraft world

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, minecraft

Whenever I open a world in the Minecraft Regrowth Modpack, Curse, all my sounds stop playing. This does not just refer to Minecraft audio, but also to Chrome (YouTube) and the System sounds.

This only happens when I am using my Bluetooth Headset, when I disconnect the Headset and use the wired speakers instead, it works just fine. Once I leave the world, the sounds instantly start playing again.

The Windows Mixer shows the sound as well, it just does not play.

Comment: When you say "the wired speakers work just fine" do you mean that when the problem occurs, the sound still comes out of your wired speakers. Or do you mean that when you turn off your Bluetooth headset, close Minecraft, and retry, it still works? Could you elaborate on the *exact* sequence of actions you take, and what happens exactly when?

Comment: Have you tried the [Audio Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/instantanswers/a183aa8b-0eac-4566-867a-98d2761a770d/fix-sound-problems#no-sound=windows-8&v1h=win8tab1&v2h=win7tab1&v3h=winvistatab1&v4h=winxptab1)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, I did, but to no effect. Wouter: Edited for clarification, I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is kind of an odd thing and was not yet mentioned anywhere, I thought I might just leave the solution here for the next one to have this problem:

If you right click the Sound symbol on the right of the task bar, click "Playback devices" and select the "Bluetooth Handsfree Audio" and disconnect it. Not permanent, it has to be done after every reconnect over Bluetooth, but it works. Of course, if anyone knows a permanent solution for this, feel free to post it.